# Is it illegal to smoke marijuana, or be caught with it, or both?

Tags: united-states, immigration, borders

I am currently watching a TV show called Border Security, and in this show, immigration officers interview potential candidates for entry into their country, in suspicion that they may have something to do with narcotics.

Usually what I see is that the immigrations officers say something along the lines of this:

**I don't care if you have smoken pot on your own free time or in the past, you simply cannot be transporting any across the border**

As I am not a citizen of the USA, I have a couple of questions.

1) Is **smoking** pot illegal?

2) Is it only illegal **if you are caught with it in your possession?**

3) If someone has admitted to smoking pot in the **past, but do not have it on them**, can they still go to jail?

4) Many of the immigrants on Border Security have admitted to smoking pot within the last week, but they are still allowed across the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marijuana for recreational usage is still illegal in 42 states in the US. The only states where [marijuana is legal](http://www.businessinsider.com/where-can-you-legally-smoke-weed-2017-1) are: Alaska, California, Colorado, Maine, Massachusetts, Nevada, Oregon, Washington, and the District of Columbia.

1. Smoking pot for recreational usage is illegal in those states other than what is listed above.
2. This depends. If your property is being searched for another crime and they find marijuana, then you could also be charged with possession of marijuana.
3. No, you most likely will not be taken to jail if you admitted to smoking marijuana in the past.
4. That is because the individuals are not committing a crime right there and then. Many people have committed crime in the past (i.e. steal candy from a store, consumed alcohol before 21 in the US, etc) but carry on with their lives and don't get charged with a crime when they admit to it later.

Comment: Also, *saying* you smoked pot (or committed any other crime) is not evidence - it's just talking. Some people have been known to tell lies.

Comment: Isn't marijuana classified as a schedule 1 drug by the DEA making its use illegal in the entire country? I don't believe failing to enforce a law does not make the law go away. Or was there some other change I'm unaware of?

Comment: It's not illegal in the entire country, the above states allow recreational usage of marijuana, as long as it's not in public: https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/marijuanainfodenver/residents-visitors

Comment: @MichaelC. So can states now preempt federal laws, or is there some reason the federal prohibition against schedule 1 drugs doesn't apply? Are you saying this answer is wrong: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/4322/1340

Comment: @MichaelC. See: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/20012/1340